# What is an eloquent word for a disrespectful, impertinent child?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I’m looking for a word that denotes a child (either a young one or a fully grown one) who acts disrespectfully and spitefully toward their parents.

For instance, if you see your friend being disrespectful toward his or her parent, you might ask your friend,

> Why are you acting like a ________ ?

An adverbial form would be sufficient too, like

> “Why are you acting [adverbial form of word]?”

I do not want any words that have connotations of annoying, whiny, irritating, etc. This includes “brat,” “rascal,” etc.

The word can be archaic (that is, old-fashioned) but preferably not obsolete (i.e. no longer used at all).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82031/discussion-on-question-by-the-wordsmith-what-is-an-eloquent-word-for-a-disrespec). Further comments will be deleted without notice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82034/discussion-between-lumberjack-and-the-wordsmith).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few of the eloquent as well as euphemistic words use to present disrespectful and impertinent kid(s) or person are:

## impudently (adverb) [**<sub>ODO</sub>**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impudently)

> *Meaning:* rude and not showing respect, especially towards someone who is older or in a more important position
>
> > *Usage:* an **impudent** child

## malapert (noun) [**<sub>ODO</sub>**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/malapert)

[*archaic*]

> :(of person)
>
> *Meaning:* An impudent person.
>
> > *Usage:* "A child's outcry, more **malapert** than the priest, called the attention of the lingerers, and before any one knew, the passion of destruction had seized like a frenzy upon the people."

Above is an excerpt from the book: [Royal Edinburgh: Her Saints, Kings, Prophets and Poets by Mrs. Oliphant](https://www.wordnik.com/words/malapert)

Collins dictionary also suggest [**malapertly**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/malapert) (adverb)

Comment: That’s more like! *Malapert* is the closest word so far!

Comment: It's great this suggestion works for the OP, but as a matter of good practice, you probably shouldn't be entirely rewriting an answer. If you feel like you need to entirely redo, post a separate answer so the new suggestions can be judged on their own _separately_. It's very disconcerting for a user to vote one way, and then accidentally revisit (no one scans visited questions/answers to look for changes) and find that the text has been changed in a different direction, falsifying the original vote. Sure, the system allows a change in vote then, but the system doesn't inform you of a change.

Comment: @Mitch: I'm not sure. I get your point, but, on the other hand, I feel people can do whatever they want with their answer in most respects.

Answer (score -1):

**Brat** and **punk** come to mind, followed by a long list of apt, witty, precise, but, alas, mostly outdated, words.

UPD:

Since the OP does not mind (he just said so), here are some words that may strike some people as way out of date:

**imp:** little devil (applied to children)

**urchin:** a mischievous boy

**rascal:** dishonest or unscrupulous person; and mischief maker when applied to kids

**scamp:** very naughty young person

Comment: I don’t mind if a word is “outdated”; that isn’t a bad thing.

Comment: Yes, where is this “list”?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I thought I had commented here with a bunch of words, but I don't know where it went. something about brat and punk not being outdated.  Oh... alist that Ricky mentioned. Hm, yeah, where is _that_?

Comment: @TheWordsmith: Just updated the answer. Please find the list in it.

Comment: @Ricky Those aren’t outdated words.

Comment: Oh yeah, just remembered. a brat whines to his parents that he didn't want that color bike for Christmas. A punk whines to his parents that he doesn't care whose needle he uses to shoot heroin. Parents, amirite!

Comment: @TheWordsmith: They're sure to get you some odd looks if you use them publicly. Well, it seems I've already gotten three downvotes for my pains. One more and I'll have to delete.

Comment: @Ricky That doesn’t make them outdated.

Comment: These are all good; however, I would not say eloquent.